# Direct path insert via db link

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, append, dblink

i have two databases I will call LOCAL and REMOTE. I understand and have confirmed that running the following from LOCAL will not result in direct path insert:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO REMOTE_TABLE@REMOTEDB
SELECT * FROM LOCAL_TABLE;
```

but running the following from REMOTE does result in a direct path insert:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO REMOTE_TABLE
SELECT * FROM LOCAL_TABLE@LOCALDB;
```

My problem is that I need to run the process from my LOCAL database. So I created a procedure on the remote database as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_LOAD AS
BEGIN
  INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO REMOTE_TABLE
  SELECT * FROM LOCAL_TABLE@LOCALDB;
END;
```

And I ran the procedure from LOCAL database:

```
BEGIN
  MY_LOAD@REMOTEDB;
END;
```

But it does not do a direct path insert.

Can anyone confirm that yes, this will not do a direct path insert? Can anyone offer an  alternative way to do direct path insert?

Big picture requirements are to copy all or a subset of rows from a partition in LOCAL database to a partition in REMOTE database. The destination table is in LOGGING mode, so the plan is to direct load INSERT into a NOLOGGING staging table on the REMOTE database and then swap this table with the destination partition.

Comment: What do you mean by direct load the query you wrote to call procedure is a direct load itself except the fact that internally it is processing from (select * from table) to insert as append operation.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, by direct load I mean this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58227/ch_dlins.htm

When it does not do a direct load it does a 'conventional load'.

Comment: Actually the thing is you can create a view as (select * from table ) to direct load in the prior case insert is a append mode load. Only creating from select works as a direct load

Comment: And i dont understand you have so much in this article why not you first understand from this article itself parallel insert load might be handy in your case as you want direct load and you can try nologging as well to remove logs

Answer (score 0):

You mean [Direct-Path INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423), this feature has a number of restriction, one of them is

> A transaction containing a direct-path INSERT statement cannot be or become distributed.

which exactly describes your observation. You'd have to initiate the transaction from a connection to the REMOTE site, so you'll direct path INSERT in a local table getting data via DB link.

Your approach with remote procedure call doesn't work as this opens a distributed transactions.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I suppose I foolishly thought that would be a workaround. Do you have any suggestions for another workaround. The problem is that the code is on the local database. It does a direct path insert and partition exchange on the local database, then wants to send data to the remote database to do the same thing. If I have the code on the remote database, then can't do a direct path insert and partition exchange on local. I suppose one way is to send a message to the remote database to get it to start a scheduled job.

Comment: Yes this would work. Define a scheduler job on the remote DB and run it when required.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_LOAD
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT /*+ APPEND */
  INTO REMOTE_TABLE
    (COLUM1,COULMN2
    )
  SELECT COLUMN1,COULMN2 FROM LOCAL_TABLE@LOCALDB;
END;
---OR---------
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_LOAD
AS
TYPE T_BULK_COLLECT
IS
  TABLE OF REMOTE_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
  L_BULK T_BULK_COLLECT;
  CURSOR C1
  IS
    SELECT * FROM LOCAL_TABLE@LOCALDB;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO L_BULK LIMIT 1000;
    FORALL I IN 1 .. L_BULK.COUNT
    INSERT INTO REMOTE_TABLE VALUES L_BULK;
    (I );
    EXIT
  WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END;
```